# Haskell Less Input Testing Boilerplate

Tags: haskell

Suppose I would like to write a bunch of functions, say `func0` to `func9`. They take the same input but do different things with them. However, all of them involve the same input check. For example:

```
func0 :: Int -> [a] -> Either String a
func0 i lst
    | i < 0 || i > length lst = Left "Index Out of Bounds!"
    | otherwise = -- does things
```

The part that checks the index out of bounds is identical for each function, so I would like to not repeat them for each function. Is there any `do` wizardry to clean the code up a little bit? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This probably isn't actually what you want to do, since it will make all of the functions be strict in the spine of the list for no good reason. Can you post exactly what the functions are actually going to do after the check?

Comment: Use **refinement type** for this case instead of one validation implementation at a time. **LiquidHaskell** is an excellent choice for this type of validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the bounds check in the indexing function. Like this:

```
(!?) :: [a] -> Int -> Either String a
lst !? i = case drop i lst of
    _ | i < 0 -> bad
    [] -> bad
    a:_ -> Right a
    where bad = Left "Index Out of Bounds!"
```

Now you can write `func0` and friends in terms of it without checking the index first, as in:

```
func0 :: Num a => Int -> [a] -> Either String a
func0 i lst = do
    a <- lst !? (i-1)
    a' <- lst !? (i+1)
    return (a+a')
```

Comment: I modified your code a little. I don't think the validation function should change the type of the output so something like 
```
isValid i lst
    | i < 0 || i >= length lst = Left "Index Out of Bounds!"
    | otherwise = Right last
```
might better isolate the validation from the actual function?

Comment: @w41g87 But it isn't a validation function. It's an *indexing* function. What other operation could usefully be done with a validated index than using it to do indexing? (You can't add or subtract, e.g.) Merging the operations this way also protects you from accidentally validating an index with respect to one list but using it to index into another list.

Comment: @w41g87 That said, if you do want to have a function that only does validation and not indexing, then the standard thing to do would be to use the type `Int -> [a] -> Either String ()`, not `Int -> [a] -> Either String [a]` as your comment seems to be suggesting. Use would then look like `func0 i lst = do { validate (i-1) lst; validate (i+1) lst; return ((lst !! i-1) + (lst !! i+1)) }`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty straightforward to factor out into a higher-order function:

```
check :: (Int -> [a] -> Either String a) -> Int -> [a] -> Either String a
check f i as
    | i < 0 || i >= length as = Left "Index Out of Bounds!"
    | otherwise = f i as

func0 = check myFunc0

func1 = check myFunc1
```

and so on, where `myFunc0` etc are the parts of the functions which presumably have different behaviour.

(It's not clear what they do, if they all just give a `Right` value then you probably want to alter them so they simply return an `a` and put the wrapping in `Right` in the `otherwise` clause of `check`. But the above allows you to return a `Left` failure value in other circumstances if you need to.)

(I've also changed `i > length as` to `i >= length as` because `i = length as` will also cause a crash assuming you're going to use `i` as an index.)

Comment: Nit: I like the name `checked` more than `check`. When applied to, e.g., `head`, it yields a checked version of `head`.

Comment: I didn't think too much about the name to be honest. I know naming is very important in software development but without more context on what the OP is doing I figure I'm not going to be able to come up with a "good" one on my own.